# Apt-get installed programs in Debian Cinnamon Desktop

Tags: debian, cinnamon

I usually use GNOME as a desktop for Debian and when I install a program like Terminator via `apt` I can immediately find it in the drop-down menu and drag a shortcut to it in the toolbar if I like.

I decided to try Cinnamon with a Debian VM I created, however I'm unable to find any of the programs I've installed via `apt` in the menu.

The programs are there, because I can run them from the command line. Launching them from the command line is not preferable though, both because it takes longer than clicking a shortcut and because it makes it such that I have to keep the original terminal running while using whatever program I launch from it.

Is there either a way to make these programs automatically show up in the menu or can I find them in the filesystem somewhere and add a toolbar shortcut that way? Terminator is suitable for an example. I tried finding it with `find` and by looking in `bin` but I didn't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/4686) for that issue.

Options are to:

1. Log out and back in again.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then press <kbd>r</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart Cinnamon.

Comment: That explains it, thanks. Just for the record when I tried #2 it resulted in the background turning black and the taskbar disappearing, so I guess it had some trouble restarting.

Comment: That's odd. I've used it a few times and not noticed that.  However, I'm using a different distro.